# Installing SwingX 1.0 to NetBeans 6.7.1

Tags: netbeans, netbeans6.7, swingx

Has anyone successfully installed [SwingX](https://swingx.dev.java.net/) to NetBeans' Palette? I'm following the instructions in [SwingX Wiki](http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Javadesktop/SwingXIDE#FirstTopic), but with some glitches:

The components appear in the Palette, but their icons won't show up correctly. If I add the componets shown by "Show All JavaBeans" (instead of "Show Marked JavaBeans") in the Palette manager, then I get some icons there, but they're for the BeanInfo objects only: for instance there's an `JXTaskPaneContainer` item with an icon, but it turns out to actually be an `JXTaskPaneContainerBeanInfo` class. The real `JXTaskPaneContainer` component is shown with a question mark icon.

Apparently NetBeans can't read the BeanInfo stuff from where it it is. I don't know if this is a SwingX issue, a NetBeans issue or a compatibility issue. Any tips?

Comment: I think I face quite the same problem with JFormDesigner. Adding the swingx components to the palette works (with default icons) but I cannot use them inside the GUI designer. I have a forbidden overlay when I try to Drag&Drop the component.

Answer (score 2):

Works fine: http://www.thainetbeans.com/sample/swingx.htm